# Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse) fails on startup: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: url

Tags: java, eclipse

Yesterday STS was working fine. Today when I try to open STS, it fails with the following message: An error has occurred. See the log file ...

When I open up the log file, I see this:

```
!SESSION 2019-06-14 12:39:17.390 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.9.0.201707061903-RELEASE-e46
java.version=1.8.0_201
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-06-14 12:39:22.351
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: url
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.initializeImages(Workbench.java:1898)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Has anyone else experienced this error before?

Answer (score 1):

First, we're sorry you ran into this rather disruptive problem - this issue affected Eclipse Neon users who had the DevStyle Icon Designer installed.

I realize you fixed the problem by removing all the theming plugins, though deleting only the `com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.icon.designer_1.11.0.201906121516` plugin is sufficient to fix this issue, and retain your customized themes.

Please see [this post](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/unable-to-launch-eclipse-neon-nosuchfielderror-url/) for further details and a simple workaround. Again, apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the following .jar files from the plugins directory:

```
com.genuitec.eclipse.core.common.platform_13.0.2.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.inlinesearch_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.meexplorer.jdt_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.meexplorer_13.0.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.monitor_13.0.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.news_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.patches_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.startup.workspace_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.startup_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.base.win_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.base_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.css_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.epl_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.icon.designer_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.scrollbar.win_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.scrollbar_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.ui_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.ui.common.platform_13.0.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.webclipse.evergreen_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipse.webicons_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
com.genuitec.eclipsecolortheme.api_1.11.0.201906121516.jar
```

I believe these .jar files pertain to the marketplace color schemes that I had previously downloaded for Eclipse.